# saving and load database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I want to save and load database on disk.

What I really want is to be able to do the typical application `save as` and `open` things with the database. Means when I want to save the database, I will click the `save as` button, and give a name to the database, and then save it. Later I want to be able to `load` back the database, by using open button to find the path to the database.

I'm using sqlite and java, and I heard that firefox bookmark manager using sqlite to store bookmarked data. And I don't know the correct term but roughly I want to be able to do like firefox bookmark manager to save and load the database.

Hope you guys can shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLite database files in two possible ways:

1. **Like a database:** Upon the first run of your application, you create the SQLite database file and create the schema (using `CREATE TABLE` SQL commands etc.). Then, whenever you want to change the saved data, you access your database file and execute single `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements to modify exactly those records that have changed. This makes operations such as *Save as* not quite straightforward, but it's comparably fast for large amounts of data where only small parts are modified.
2. **Like a data file:** Every time you save your data, you create a new database file (if there was one with the same name before, you delete it first). You then create the whole schema, and then you write all the information to the database file (using `INSERT` SQL statements). This allows you to handle things with the traditional *Save*/*Save as* commands.

For more detailed information, please ask more specifically; in particular, outline your problem if you need to know which approach serves you best.

Comment: basically im developing simple family tree application for my grad project. basically i need this because user might want to create more than one "family chart", so i want "each family" to be save and load from different database.

Comment: That is possible with both approaches, but replicating the well-known *Save* / *Save as* pattern is probably indeed a good choice for end-users.

Comment: do you know any good tutorial site? and what is the correct term that i can use to google for the tutorial?

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for: Do you need to learn SQL first? => Look for an SQL tutorial (there are plenty). Do you need to know how to create and open SQLite files? => Check your Java SQLite wrapper docs; they should explain these basic tasks with the particular wrapper you're using.

Comment: im using http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

could you direct me to tutorial for the purpose of saving database like a data file? i know the basic sql like how to connect, get, save, delete form the typical dabatase type, but not this that i want to learn.

Comment: The sample code on the page you just linked to shows quite a good example of how to save a datafile. Look at the line where `getConnection` is invoked: The connection string indicates that an SQLite file named `test.db` is created. After that, the schema is created (a single table named `people` in that case), and some data is inserted with `insert` SQL commands. Once the connection is eventually closed, the data file is saved on disk.
When loading data, do it the same way, but don't overwrite the schema and execute `select` commands to retrieve the data.